# How do I make my kernel module's sysfs entry be owned by a non-root user?

Tags: linux, kernel, sysfs, file-ownership

I have the following code:

```
static struct kobj_attribute my_attribute =__ATTR(my_node, 0444, my_show_fn, my_store_fn);
...
        kobject_init(&my_module->kobj, &ktype_my_module);
        ret = kobject_add(&my_module->kobj, kernel_kobj, "%s", "my_module");
        ...
        ret = sysfs_create_file(&my_module->kobj, &my_attribute.attr);
```

This creates a `/sys/kernel/my_module/my_node node`, owned by root with 0444 permissions.

How can I make a non-root user own this node, from within the kernel code?

Comment: Have you tried to change ownership of the node after sysfs_create_file ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes this works, but for my use case only it's better to set it in the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Owner's and group's identifiers of a sysfs attribute are determined by the the **kobject** for which this attribute is created.

Specifically, it is `get_ownership` field of the `struct kobj_type` which may contain a callback for set owner's and group's identifiers. The field has following signature:

```
struct kobj_type {
    ...
    void (*get_ownership)(struct kobject *kobj, kuid_t *uid, kgid_t *gid);
};
```

When the callback is called, both `*uid` and `*gid` contain 0 (which corresponds to the root user). The callback may set these output parameters to other values.